# prism/mvvm: binding Columns to DataGrid

Tags: wpf, binding, mvvm, datagrid, prism

I'm using a standard .NET DataGrid like this:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Datensaetze}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
 <DataGrid.Columns>
   <DataGridTextColumn Header="my col 1" Binding="{Binding MyCol1}"/>
   <DataGridTextColumn Header="my col 2" Binding="{Binding MyCol2}"/>
   <DataGridTextColumn Header="my col 3" Binding="{Binding MyCol3}"/>
 </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

This is working nicely. Now I want to define the columns in the ViewModel, and instead of setting fixed columns in xaml I want to generate them on the fly. However, if I try to bind the Columns to anything I get an error, saying

> DataGrid.Columns is a readonly property and can't be bound.

Is there a way to dynamically bind the DataGrid columns to something in code behind?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, the Columns Property is ReadOnly so we can't bind to it directly. If you want to Bind Columns then you can try to use an attached property which you bind to, which in turn updates the Columns.

**Update**
Using delta of changes in the CollectionChanged event.

```
public class DataGridColumnsBehavior
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BindableColumnsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("BindableColumns",
                                            typeof(ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>),
                                            typeof(DataGridColumnsBehavior),
                                            new UIPropertyMetadata(null, BindableColumnsPropertyChanged));
    private static void BindableColumnsPropertyChanged(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGrid dataGrid = source as DataGrid;
        ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn> columns = e.NewValue as ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>;
        dataGrid.Columns.Clear();
        if (columns == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        foreach (DataGridColumn column in columns)
        {
            dataGrid.Columns.Add(column);
        }
        columns.CollectionChanged += (sender, e2) =>
        {
            NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs ne = e2 as NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs;
            if (ne.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset)
            {
                dataGrid.Columns.Clear();
                foreach (DataGridColumn column in ne.NewItems)
                {
                    dataGrid.Columns.Add(column);
                }
            }
            else if (ne.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
            {
                foreach (DataGridColumn column in ne.NewItems)
                {
                    dataGrid.Columns.Add(column);
                }
            }
            else if (ne.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move)
            {
                dataGrid.Columns.Move(ne.OldStartingIndex, ne.NewStartingIndex);
            }
            else if (ne.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
            {
                foreach (DataGridColumn column in ne.OldItems)
                {
                    dataGrid.Columns.Remove(column);
                }
            }
            else if (ne.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace)
            {
                dataGrid.Columns[ne.NewStartingIndex] = ne.NewItems[0] as DataGridColumn;
            }
        };
    }
    public static void SetBindableColumns(DependencyObject element, ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn> value)
    {
        element.SetValue(BindableColumnsProperty, value);
    }
    public static ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn> GetBindableColumns(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>)element.GetValue(BindableColumnsProperty);
    }
}
```

Then you can bind the BindableColumns property to your ColumnsCollection

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          local:DataGridColumnsBehavior.BindableColumns="{Binding ColumnCollection}">
    <!-- ... -->
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: I've been using this fine, but I've run into a problem where I need to update the ObservableCollection on a background thread (I'm using the Dispatcher to do this). The above code then falls over in the CollectionChanged delegate with the error "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it". Any suggestions what I can do?

Comment: I am in the same situation as Andrew Stephens. Can't find a way around that. Anyone help?

Comment: I think you have to unbind the items source first before you can update it in the background thread. You can't access any object bound to a UI(with raisepropertychanged/collectionchanged) in the background thread. Another option is to use a different object that you should change/access in the background thread. Then use Continue with (if you're using task) then pass that object to the ContinueWith block.

Comment: Just a follow up question to this solution, now that I have a dynamic column, How can I have a dynamic item source /cell value to this column?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it, I just made an indexed property and bind it to the column using the column header.

Comment: very nice。But better with sample code of ColumnCollection definition.