# Binding a grid to a list of list of objects

Tags: silverlight, list, binding, grid

I have an ObservableCollection> myData

And let's say MyObject has 5 properties : Prop1, Prop2, Prop3, Prop4, Prop5

I would like to show those lists in a grid that would look like this :

----myData[0] (a List)------|----myData[1] (a List)------|

Prop1 | Prop2 | Prop3 | Prop4 | Prop5 | Prop1 | Prop2 | Prop3 | Prop4 | Prop5 |

How should I bind my columns display the data of the correct List of MyObject ?

Thanks !

Comment: Do you want to show it in a "Grid" or in a "DataGrid"??

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is similar to this:
[prism/mvvm: binding Columns to DataGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367264/prism-mvvm-binding-columns-to-datagrid)