# WPF MVVM Dynamically bind datagrid columns to collection

Tags: wpf, mvvm, wpfdatagrid

I have a request where I need to design a WPF screen using MVVM. This screen has two DataGrids.

The first datagrid will be bound to a collection where the datagrid will be able to add or remove items from it.

Now, the tricky part is that I need the second DataGrid to have its columns automatically generated from the items in the collection that the first datagrid is bound to.

Example:

If the first DataGrid has three lines:

```
| Value 1 |
| Value 2 |
| Value 3 |
```

I need my second datagrid to have those three columns:

```
| Value 1 | Value 2 | Value 3 |
```

However, I'm trying to think of a way to implement this which doesn't involve manually adding those columns to the second datagrid, because I believe that would kill the "MVVM way" of doing things for two reasons:

1. I want the code-behind file for my view to remain "empty" (I cannot add any code to it other than the automatically generated "InitializeCOmponent()" on the view's constructor)
2. I can't let my ViewModel to actually hold a reference to the DataGrid, as I believe that would create a strong tie from the View to the ViewModel.

Because of those two reasons, does anyone know a way of doing this involving only bindings (or other solutions that don't break those two rules?)

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367264/prism-mvvm-binding-columns-to-datagrid

Answer (score 1):

1. Bind a `DataTable` to the `first` DataGrid.
2. Then `transpose` the DataTable (Exchange rows and columns) and bind it to the `second` DataGrid.

Here you have to set the `AutoGeneratedColumns` property of the DataGrid to `true`.

Please look at this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/44274/Transpose-a-DataTable-using-C) to transpose a DataTable.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15780178/873979) is a simple solution to bind `DataTable` to a DataGrid.

If you already have bound a `Collection` to the first DataGrid, you can define a `new` DataTable and `logically assigned` values from the Collection and then you can bind the DataTable to the DataGrid too.